# Ошибка при apt update

Tags: linux, debian, update, repository, apt

Ввожу sudo apt update и у меня возникает ошибка:

> The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu
>   groovy Release' does not have a Release file. N: Updating from such a
>   repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by
>   default. N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user
>   configuration details.

```
[~] sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease                           
Ign:2 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu groovy InRelease                             
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease                                                 
Hit:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease                                         
Hit:5 https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable InRelease                                  
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu groovy Release                               
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Hit:7 https://repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease                                                   
Hit:8 https://repo.windscribe.com/debian buster InRelease                                     
Hit:9 https://packagecloud.io/AtomEditor/atom/any any InRelease         
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu groovy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Как пофиксить это?
p.s Debian 10

Comment: Вы пробовали перевести сообщение с ошибкой? Там просят указывать `https` для `ppa` резпозиториев.

Comment: и то верно. аффтар - правь /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: @AndreyMihalev, если каталог `http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu/groovy` не существует, то он не появится и по ссылке `https://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/atom/ubuntu/groovy`